# Warning: "my page" is unreachable

Tags: facebook, web-applications

Ok, so i am developing a new site, and it is very dependent of facebook.

I have looked everywhere and done everything i should but i keep getting this message in my FB comment area: **Warning: http://www.videozoo.dk/?videos=klo-aben is unreachable**

My header looks as it should like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<meta property="fb:admins" content="my fb id nr"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="195385377211689">
<meta property="og:title" content="Videozoo.dk - Dyre video" />
<meta property="og:type" content="Video" />
<meta property="og:url" content="www.videozoo.dk/?videos=klo-aben" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Dyre videoer for alle!"/>
<meta property="og:description"
content="Endnu en dyre video på VideoZoo.dk"/>
```

My fb comment code looks like this:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="www.videozoo.dk/?videos=klo-aben" data-num-posts="10" data-width="640" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

My app id for this comment box was made 4 hours ago so it should be updated on the servers by now...

The information in the app matches what is stated above:

Application ID/API Key:
195385377211689

Site-URL:
http://www.videozoo.dk/

Domain:
videozoo.dk

**BUT** - It is still not working! - is it because my site is new or mabye because the app is not updated on the servers yet??

Please have a closer look and maybe test at this link: www.videozoo.dk/?videos=klo-aben

All ideas are welcome!!

Answer (score 1):

You left the protocol out of your value for `og:url`, include it there and it may solve the issue, the scraper follows HTTP or og:url redirects, and that URL is likely detected as invalid

{edit} I figured this out, and it's a bit strange, but... {/edit}
When I manually scrape that page it seems to work fine, but when I run it through the URL Debugger it fails due to a HTTP 403 response from your side

I've seen this before with other servers which can't handle some part of Facebook's request - in this case it seems to be because your server is rejecting the request if a [HTTP 'Range' header](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/http/draft-fielding-http/p5-range.html#header.range) is sent.

Facebook's crawler only requests the first 40KB of the document when scraping, as the meta tags should be in the `<head></head>` section

My test was:

```
$ curl -I -H 'Range: bytes=0-40960' 'http://www.videozoo.dk/?videos=klo-aben'
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Wed, 30 Nov 2011 14:17:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.6 mod_auth_kerb/5.3 PHP/5.2.17 mod_fcgid/2.3.5
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

$ curl -I 'http://www.videozoo.dk/?videos=klo-aben'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 30 Nov 2011 14:18:02 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.6 mod_auth_kerb/5.3 PHP/5.2.17 mod_fcgid/2.3.5
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

I'm not sure if this is something in your code, server config, an intermediate proxy, etc, but it's very likely the cause of your problem

Comment: hey Thanks...Can you tell me exactly how that is done? maybe an example of how it should look...

Comment: Hmm...changed it to `http://www.videozoo.dk/?videos=klo-aben`...still dont seem to work

Comment: updated answer, seems it wasn't related to the og:url tag afterall

Comment: Thank you very much for your time!... It seems a bit complicated i must say ;) - Stragely enough i have two other domains on the same server, and facbook can easily find them ( beginnertuts.com as an example) I just tried testing with a plain index.php fil only containing the fb code and som general headers and it could not find the page...ill try removing everything from the folder and install try making a index.php file only contaning the FB comment box to se weather it is my code or theme that is the problem...

Comment: Hey again... so now the only think that is on my site is a index page containing the FB comment code... Still get an error...i guess it must be the server... Se the index file here http://www.videozoo.dk/

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure how to debug this further, I don't know why the presence of a Range header would cause the request to fail

Comment: Ok...you have been very helpfull soo far! thank you! i am starting to think that it is because i just bought the domain yesterday and manbye my DNS is not 100% up an running yet...anyways, i have contacted my hotsing provider to ask them ;)